# Delete single window frame after app quits

Tags: window, frames

Some of the apps (w3m, elfeed, mu4e, to name a few) when quit leave unused frame so the other buffer shows up in their place. Over time these redundant frames pile up, so we have to delete them.

I look for a way to automate it, by deleting these frames if there is only one window inside with an app that just quit. I want to use it for buffers used by `w3m`, `mu4e`, `elfeed`, `erc`.

If we just close the frame, the app will still be lurking around. The next time I will need it and call the command it may create another instance instead of reusing existing one. That's why it would be better to delete the frame on app quit rather than keeping it alive without active window.

It would be perfect to configure it selectively using `display-buffer-alist` if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not simply delete the frame, `C-x 5 0` rather than the window `C-x 0`?

Comment: I can, but It doesn't solve the problem since I want to close an app as well. I case of w3m I often close entire app by just pressing Q.

Comment: @farynaio: In that case, your question isn't clear (complete). It's apparently not just about deleting the frame when you delete a window. Deleting a window (`C-x 0`) does not close any app, and it's not bound to the same command as `q` (or `Q` presumably). Please specify what you do and what you want, completely, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: @Drew you are right. Sorry for confusion allsOrts. I amended the question and title.